# Create Stripe token without elements

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a Stripe toke, but without `elements`.

This is my code:

```
   stripe.createToken('person', {
            card: '4242424242424242'
        }, function(err, token) {
        console.log(token)
        // asynchronously called
    });
```

The error in the console is:

> Unrecognized token creation parameter parameter: card is not a recognized parameter. This may cause issues with your integration in the future.

The response error is:

> You must supply either a card, customer, PII data, bank account, or account legal entity to create a token. If you're making this request with a library, be sure to pass all of the required parameters for creating a token. If you're making this request manually, be sure your POST parameters begin with the token type. For...

I can't find in the docs, which params, I must add.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create a token using a raw credit card in the current version of Stripe's APIs. You must use an [element](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js). While this is not explicitly stated in the `createToken` documentation, there is a notice in the `createSource` docs:

> You cannot pass raw card information to stripe.createSource(sourceData). Instead, you must gather card information in an Element and use stripe.createSource(element, sourceData). You can also pass an existing card token to convert it into a Source object.

If you absolutely do not want to create an element, you could use the deprecated [Stripe.card.createToken](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#collecting-card-details) v2 API, but this is not recommended.

Comment: Why is that not recommended?